# PS3 backup with another HDD

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

My PS3 died with YLOD couple of weeks ago and I got my new PS3 with 160GB hdd today. I also have my old hdd with 500GB including all my game saves. Can I somehow restore my game saves to the new hdd with the older one?

If I use SATA to USB -cable to connect my old hdd to PS3, can I restore my old gamedata that way (in the same way as regular USB-stick)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My PS3 died with YLOD couple of weeks ago and I got my new PS3 with 160GB hdd today. I also have my old hdd with 500GB including all my game saves. Can I somehow restore my game saves to the new hdd with the older one?

Only if you saved them to the cloud. ie. if you have PS+ membership and have been backing up your saves.

Some saved games can be copied to a USB drive (but not all), but it doesn't sound like you've been doing this.

> If I use SATA to USB -cable to connect my old hdd to PS3, can I restore my old gamedata that way (in the same way as regular USB-stick)?

No.

The hard disk in the PS3 is encrypted and can only be read in the PS3 that created the data in the first place. Since that PS3 is not working, there is no way to read the data from that hard disk.

Well, there is one way. Get your old PS3 repaired, either by the 'reflowing' or 'reballing' technique. (Don't send it to Sony though - last I checked their policy was to format all HDDs in PS3s received for repair. Find a 3rd party that will do it.) After this your old PS3 will work again, but don't treat this as a long-term fix - it can be expected to last maybe 3 months. Instead use this opportunity to sign up to PS+ and copy all of your saves to the cloud. Then restore your saves to your new PS3 (you might have to wait 24 hours before you can do this step).

The PS+ part is necessary because a number of saved games are copy protected, and the only way they can be transferred between systems is via the PS+ cloud. Even the backup utility feature won't transfer these files.

Answer (score -1):

If you are lucky you can just attach the SATA to USB cable and it'll show your old PS3 drive as a USB storage device.

Then simply choose what to copy from the old drive, onto the console with the 160Gb.

You *may* be able to just put the 500Gb drive into the PS3, however I'm unsure if this requires formatting it, so I'd recommend doing the above instead.

Comment: I first tried to put the 500Gb drive into the PS3. But it just said that I have to update the hdd to 4.75 (newest ps3 version) and its content will be cleared.So, I'll try to connect old hdd with SATA to USB cable. (Going to buy that cable tomorrow)

Comment: I was told that it's not possible to just attach hdd with SATA to USB cable and use it like USB storage device.

Comment: According to who?

"I plugged an external HDD/USB flash drive into my PS3, and it isn't detected.

If you want to hook up any kind of external HDD or flash drive via USB to your PS3, it needs to be formatted in FAT32. Most external HDDs that claim support with Mac/OSX will be pre-formatted in FAT32, so you won't need to worry about it."

as per https://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/ps3_hdd

Comment: PlayStation support told that I have to format my hdd to FAT32 (and formatting will erase all the memory, won't it?) and a seller at technology store told me that what I wrote in previous comment (can't use hdd as USB storage without formatting). EDIT: Sorry, I wrote previous comment in hurry and that is why I forgot to add these information)

Answer (score -2):

This might NOT work,but have you thought of just swapping the HDs? pop open that little door on the bottom of the unit with your thumb nail,Then,unscrew the little screw and while its still upside down, slid the little door to the left. Then,lift up the little hard-wire handle and pull. HD removal complete. NEXT,just replace the new one with the old one,put it back togather, and when you fire it up, save all your game saves to the cloud. I hope this helps you,
Skintech

Comment: You can't swap old hdd (which you have been used in another PS3) to new PS3 without formatting it (and thus clearing all the data).  This is made for preventing piracy..